# show next custom error message if user enter only first input in any row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

iam working on form validation, my requirement is show erro message if user did not fill all field in a row. in my page there are two rows every row contains two input fields. when i click submit button when all fields are empty it should show error. page first two inputs working. when user enter first field the next field also mandatory. no need of second row, if user filled first row and also filed second row first field, the second row second field mandatory.
    in this manner is my requirement i have written some code.
    Thanks in advance.

**HTML**

```js
function crtNewRelease() {
  var versionIpa = document.getElementById("versionIpa");
  var version1Error = document.getElementById("version1Error");
  var selectDevice1 = document.getElementById("selectDevice1");
  var selectDevice1Error = document.getElementById("selectDevice1Error");
  var versionApk = document.getElementById("versionApk");
  var version2Error = document.getElementById("version2Error");
  var selectDevice2 = document.getElementById("selectDevice2");
  var selectDevice2Error = document.getElementById("selectDevice2Error");
  if (sltProject.value == "") {
    sltProject.style.border = "solid 1px red";
    firstNError.textContent = "Select Project";
    firstNError.style.color = "red";
    firstNError.style.marginTop = "10px"
    sltProject.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (releaseName.value == "") {
    releaseName.style.border = "solid 1px red";
    lastNError.textContent = "Enter Release Name";
    lastNError.style.color = "red";
    lastNError.style.marginTop = "10px"
    releaseName.focus();
    return false;
  }
  var sameCls = document.getElementsByClassName("newformInputs");
  var inputArray = [];
  var result;
  var i = 1
  for (i = 1; i < sameCls.length; i++) {
    result += sameCls[i]
    if (result == 1) {
      version1Error.textContent = "Enter version";
      return false;
    } else {
      version1Error.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="createNewRelease" onsubmit="return crtNewRelease();">
  <select class="form-control" id="sltProject">
        <option value="">Select Project</option>
        <option value="one">one</option>
        <option value="two">two</option>
        <option value="three">Domino’s Makeline App</option>
      </select>
  <div id="firstNError" class="firstN"></div>
  <input class="form-control " placeholder="Release Name" type="text" id="releaseName">
  <div id="lastNError" class="firstN"></div>
  <div class="selectPlatform">
    <h6>Select platforms (you can select both)</h6>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <input class="form-control newformInputs" placeholder="Version number" type="text" id="versionIpa" />
        <div id="version1Error" class="firstN"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5 ">
        <select class="form-control newformInputs" id="selectDevice1">
              <option value="">Select device</option>
              <option>iPhone</option>
              <option>iPad</option>
            </select>
        <div id="selectDevice1Error" class="selectDevice1Cls"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1"> <span> </span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5 ">
        <input class="form-control newformInputs" placeholder="Version number" type="text" id="versionApk">
        <div id="version2Error" class="firstN"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5 ">
        <select class="form-control newformInputs" id="selectDevice2">
              <option value="">Select device</option>
              <option>iPhone</option>
              <option>iPad</option>
            </select>
        <div id="selectDevice2Error" class="selectDevice2Cls"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1"> <span></span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="btnsRow">
    <button class="btn" type="submit">Create Release</button>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK i add it to this code.check it!.

```
<form name="createNewRelease" onsubmit="return crtNewRelease();">
  <select class="form-control" id="sltProject">
        <option value="">Select Project</option>
        <option value="one">one</option>
        <option value="two">two</option>
        <option value="three">Domino’s Makeline App</option>
      </select>
  <div id="firstNError" class="firstN"></div>
  <input class="form-control " placeholder="Release Name" type="text" id="releaseName">
  <div id="lastNError" class="firstN"></div>
  <div class="selectPlatform">
    <h6>Select platforms (you can select both)</h6>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <input class="form-control newformInputs" placeholder="Version number" type="text" id="versionIpa" />
        <div class="error"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5 ">
        <select class="form-control newformInputs" id="selectDevice1">
              <option value="">Select device</option>
              <option>iPhone</option>
              <option>iPad</option>
            </select>
        <div class="error"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1"> <span> </span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5 ">
        <input class="form-control newformInputs" placeholder="Version number" type="text" id="versionApk">
        <div class="error"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5 ">
        <select class="form-control newformInputs" id="selectDevice2">
              <option value="">Select device</option>
              <option>iPhone</option>
              <option>iPad</option>
            </select>
        <div class="error"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1"> <span></span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="btnsRow">
    <button class="btn" type="submit">Create Release</button>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

JS :

```
function crtNewRelease() {
  var versionIpa = document.getElementById("versionIpa");
  var version1Error = document.getElementById("version1Error");
  var selectDevice1 = document.getElementById("selectDevice1");
  var selectDevice1Error = document.getElementById("selectDevice1Error");
  var versionApk = document.getElementById("versionApk");
  var version2Error = document.getElementById("version2Error");
  var selectDevice2 = document.getElementById("selectDevice2");
  var selectDevice2Error = document.getElementById("selectDevice2Error");
  if (sltProject.value == "") {
    sltProject.style.border = "solid 1px red";
    firstNError.textContent = "Select Project";
    firstNError.style.color = "red";
    firstNError.style.marginTop = "10px"
    sltProject.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (releaseName.value == "") {
    releaseName.style.border = "solid 1px red";
    lastNError.textContent = "Enter Release Name";
    lastNError.style.color = "red";
    lastNError.style.marginTop = "10px"
    releaseName.focus();
    return false;
  }
  var sameCls = document.getElementsByClassName("newformInputs");
  var inputArray = [];
  var errorPos = [];
  var result;
  var i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < sameCls.length; i++) {
    result = sameCls[i];
    if (result.value == "" ) {
            errorPos.push(i);
    } else {
      //version1Error.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  //reset error class
  var listerror = document.getElementsByClassName("error");
  for(var t5 = 0 ; t5 < listerror.length ; t5++ ){
    listerror[t5].textContent = "";
  }
  console.log(errorPos);
  var flag = false;
  if(errorPos.length > 0){
    for (i = 0; i < sameCls.length; i=i+2 ) {

        if(i % 2 == 0){
        console.log(errorPos.indexOf(i));
            if(errorPos.indexOf(i)==-1){
            if(errorPos.indexOf(i+1)==-1){
                flag = true;
            }
            else{
                flag = false;
            }

          }

        }       
    }
    if(!flag){
        for(var t2= 0 ; t2 < errorPos.length ; t2++){
      console.log(sameCls[errorPos[t2]]);
        for(var t3 = 0 ; t3 < sameCls[errorPos[t2]].parentNode.childNodes.length; t3++ ){
           if(sameCls[errorPos[t2]].parentNode.childNodes[t3].className == "error"){
              sameCls[errorPos[t2]].parentNode.childNodes[t3].textContent = "Erorr!!";
              sameCls[errorPos[t2]].parentNode.childNodes[t3].style.display = "block";
              return false;
            }
        }
      }

    }
   }
   return false;
}
```

[Check It!](https://fiddle.jshell.net/Lh0c17pz/)

Comment: no i declared it globally in my file i did not mention it in

Comment: you want to add validation for each class "newformInputs".

Comment: yes but based on row the user filled u can read my Question post

Comment: @ramu ramu : i edited my answer , check it! . hope to solve your issuse.

Comment: yeh it's showing erro message, when first row two validated second row should not show erro i mean not mandatroy, if second row two validated first row not mandatory

Comment: no it's showing four errors at a time. after validated atleast one row error message should not shown. any possibilities in jquery.

Comment: after validating first row. it's ok. even i click on the submit button. if i enter text in the second row first field that time second row second field also should be mandatory.

Comment: i add some conditions. i think it work. if each row if you enter first field without enter second field . error will be show

Comment: not showing any error why? i add that condition can u add that in the file

Comment: now its good i want input border to be red when error shows thanks buddy

Comment: if(!flag){...in here...} . you can add style you want . sameCls[errorPos[t2]].style ="..."

Comment: should i take id of the input? can u add it in code will write styles also i need to pass current element placeholder as error example "Please enter version " for all

Comment: i applied it not working (sameCls[errorPos[t2]]).style.border = "solid 1px red"; where to add and where to remove

Comment: you Assign it after this "if(!flag){ for(var t2= 0 ; t2 < errorPos.length ; t2++){ sameCls[errorPos[t2]].style.border = "solid 1px red"; "  .  And assign it free  after this "for (i = 0; i < sameCls.length; i++) {
    result = sameCls[i]; sameCls[i].style.border = "solid 0px red";" .Like that . And when you enter feild , placehoder can't show.

Comment: yeh i done it in by using blur function because i need to remove when user click out of input box